# array of struct containing 2 arrays of structs not getting initialized properly, lead to segfault

Tags: c, arrays, struct

These are my two structs:

```
struct upset {
  int location;     
  int trigger;    
  int type;      
  char bits[8]; 
  }; 

struct event {
  int category;
  int spill;
  int num_clock_ups;
  int num_data_ups;
  struct upset clock_ups[512];
  struct upset data_ups[512];
  };
```

but when i try to declare an array of struct events further down with this:

```
int nevents = 1755;
struct event total_events[nevents];
```

i get a segfault the first time i try to access anything in the array, upon checking with gdb, just before the segfault  sizeof(total_events) is 0 and the difference in locations of total_events[1] and total_events[2] is 0x10, so it seems the arrays of struct upsets are not getting intialized or something.

what did i do wrong in initializing this array? are my structs set up poorly? i am very new at structs in C and in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your process stack space big enough?  By my calculation that array is going to take up at least (ignoring potential structure member alignment padding):

```
[2*(13*512) + 4]*1755 = 22.3 MB
```

of space.  If `total_events` is a local variable, it'll be allocated on the stack.  Do you have that much stack space?

Comment: OP, if you're on OS X, here is a document with some ways to increase stack size: http://homepage.mac.com/eric.c/hpc/contents/documentation/How%20to%20increase%20the%20stack%20size%20on%20Mac%20OS%20X.pdf

Comment: Although I just noticed that you said you're a noob. Try `calloc()`ing those structs e.g. `struct event *total_events = calloc(nevents, sizeof(struct event));` Make sure to call `free(total_events)` when you're done.

Comment: how do i figure out how much stack space i have? im sshing into the school unix servers, if that changes anything.

mkb, would that alleviate any stack issues i might be having? ill definitely look at that. thanks!

Comment: and if i declare total_events as a ptr of type event, i iterate through it with `total_events++` rather than `total_events[i];i++;`, right?

Comment: @swicano - try typing `ulimit -s` at the shell prompt for the stack size limit.  (Can do `ulimit -a` to see all the various limits.)